# Dell idrac 6 Express integrated configuration

Tags: dell-poweredge

I'm racking some new Dell 310 servers and noticed that the Dell idrac6 Express does not have its own dedicated ethernet port. From what I'm reading about configuring this, I can CTRL+E during POST to configure the idrac as 'shared', give it an IP address, and have it shared with NIC1 that Windows uses so it's actually going to have 2 IP addresses? (one for idrac, one for Windows)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That's accurate.

Comment: I have an idrac set as shared and I've given it an IP address. I can ping the IP address from the network but I cannot get to a console via http, https, ssh, or telnet. Shouldn't there be a web console at this IP?